# Android and Kotlin DeteKt: Custom rules not running

Tags: android, kotlin, static-analysis, detekt

Trying to create some playground over Detekt custom rules and it just doesn't work. Doesn't even try to find the rule-set file.

The gradle goes

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt").version("1.17.1")
}
...
detekt {
    toolVersion = "$detekt_version" // 1.17.1
    input = files("src/main/java")
    config = files("../detekt/detekt-config.yml")
    autoCorrect = true
    reports { ... } 
}

dependencies {
    detektPlugins "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-formatting:$detekt_version"
    compileOnly "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-api:$detekt_version"
    detekt "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-cli:$detekt_version"
    ...
}
```

The rule goes

```
class SomeCustomRule(config: Config) : Rule(config) {
    override val issue: Issue
        get() = Issue("Import thingy", Severity.Minor, "I don't like this string", Debt(10))

    override fun visitImportDirective(importDirective: KtImportDirective) {
        val import: String = importDirective.importPath?.pathStr ?: ""
        if ("appcompat" in import) {
            report(CodeSmell(
                issue,
                Entity.from(importDirective),
                "Importing $import which is an internal import"))
        }
    }
}
```

The provider is

```
class CustomRuleSetProvider : RuleSetProvider {
    override val ruleSetId: String = "detekt-custom-rules"

    override fun instance(config: Config) = RuleSet(ruleSetId, listOf(SomeCustomRule(config)))
}
```

And last but not least

At

```
src/main/resources/META-INF/services/io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.api.RuleSetProvider
```

is

```
com.playgrounds.detekt.customrule.CustomRuleSetProvider
```

Still - nothing. I tried to add gibberish at the provider - nothing, no error. I even tried to spoil the declaration at META-INF. Nothing.

Of course I tried to add the provider into my config file, or add a project line in the gradle. Error, not recognised.

What have I missed?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, was this resolved?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, it is. Via the forum. Sorry, need to properly answer and document it. Didn’t have the time. Will send the md file the moment I prepare it

Comment: I was able to resolve it after sleeping it over the weekend.

Comment: Hi @SteveKamau How did you resolved it?

Comment: @user14387887 please come back!

Answer (score 0):

The issue probably is in having `id 'com.android.application'` in the gradle file. Please remove and keep only 2 plugins - `kotlin` and `io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt`

I've spent also some time on making custom rules working and found the next rules:

1. Create **pure** kotlin module:
   [image]
2. Ensure that `build.gradle` doesn't have redundant dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id("kotlin")
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt")
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly(libs.detekt)
}
```

3. Under the `main` create the `resource` folder.
4. Create the `config` directory and the `config.yml` file. Read documentation on how it should be filled
5. Create `META-INF.services` directory. As for me it was the biggest issue because I didn't notice `services` folder in the path
6. Then create a file with a *constant* name `io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.api.RuleSetProvider`. *Do not modify its name*
7. Instead you should provide a full class name that you've implemented as `RuleSetProvider` as file content - `com.your_package_name.RuleProvider`

[image]

8. Build the module - `:detekt-rules:assemle`
9. Enable custom rules in your general config file and invoke `./gradlew detekt`